# Twitter Bootstrap Rails Datetime picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I would like to include the following datetime picker in my rails application.

http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I am using twitter bootstrap for rails, but can't get it to work.

I tried adding the .js file to the `assets/javascripts` directory and using `//= require` to include it in the `application.js` file.

The files are loading on the page, but I'm getting a response that

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'datetimepicker'

Any ideas? I've reverted all of my changes, so can start again from scratch.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Comment: Please show application.js, as well as the js and html code to launch datetime picker

Comment: added above. Thanks Billy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem happened at `//=require_tree`. Yes you added that plugin but the plugin is loaded after your custom js which have method to call the plugin. That's why "Object has no method 'datetimepicker'".

I would suggest you to:

1. Move the plugin into `vendor/assets/javascripts/`. This is a better place for third party libs.
2. require the plugin explicitly in application, after bootstrap(it depends on bootstrap's dropdown. Like

   ```
   //= require bootstrap
   //= require datetime_picker_js_file_name
   //= require_tree .
   ```

Side notes:

I don't quite know why there are two bootstrap js files required. Are they duplicate?

Besides, I would recommend to require Bootstrap js files only on need, like

```
//= require bootstrap-dropdown
//= require bootstrap-alert
```